# Mage Wars Academy - zone spells : do they attack mages?

Tags: mage-wars

The spell Voltaic Discharge is said in the rules to target every creatures in the play area, including your own. That being said, and including the mages as creature, it seems right that it affects the opposing mage. However, if it attack your own wizard as well, its a rather poor choice of spell.
Am i wrong assuming it attacks your wizard?
if not, how can this card be used intelligently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, zone spells effect everything in the zone, including Mages, both yours and your opponent's.

In Academy, there is only one zone, so the spell effects everything in play, unless the spell states that it does not.

Two possible strategic uses could be if you were way behind in creatures, so if will effect more opposing creatures than your own, or as a way to help finish off your opponent's mage.

Comment: i suppose it's more of a deterent, like nuclear escalation.